# If exactly-once semantics are impossible, what theoretical constraint is Kafka relaxing?

Tags: apache-kafka, messaging

If [you can't have exactly-once message delivery in distributed systems](https://bravenewgeek.com/you-cannot-have-exactly-once-delivery/), but [Kafka says it does it](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/), what subtle aspect of "exactly-once" has Kafka relaxed or redefined to achieve the seemingly impossible?

Comment: Did you read the Kafka article you linked? They seemed to go into pretty thorough discussion about exactly this question there.

Comment: I did, but I feel like I'm missing something.  The first article I linked makes quite the case (convincing to me) that _anyone_ claiming to have solved this problem is ultimately relaxing one of the constraints.  It was hard to see (for me) which of the foundational constraints Kafka is relaxing; hence my question.  Could you tell me which one it is, if it is apparent from the second article?  Thanks!

Comment: Kafka supports "exact-once processing", not "exactly-once delivery". Messages can be delivered twice or more, but they will be processed only once at the receiving end.

Comment: @vahid can you explain if a message is delivered more than once - how it will be processed only once without any application side logic ? How Kafka ensures exactly once processing at the receiving side ? It does not look  like the case actually .

Comment: @KMD This is done using a sequence number to detect duplicate messages. The second link in the question explains this under "Idempotence: Exactly-once in order semantics per partition".